# Export on nodejs alpine docker image is not accepted

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I want to add a http_proxy environment variable to the nodejs alpine docker image.

The Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:6-alpine

RUN export
RUN export https_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
RUN export http_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
RUN export
```

The output when running

```
docker build -t myimage:latest .
```

looks like this

```
 Step 1/5 : FROM node:6-alpine
 ---> 66cf88e4fc20
 Step 2/5 : RUN export
  ---> Running in 61f5bda7989d
 export HOME='/root'
 export HOSTNAME='26ba10d264c2'
 export NODE_VERSION='6.9.5'
 export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL='info'
 export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
 export PWD='/'
 export SHLVL='1'
  ---> f04aeb89f7d0
 Removing intermediate container 61f5bda7989d
 Step 3/5 : RUN export https_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
  ---> Running in 895d13321da8
  ---> 6a8aaa9639a9
 Removing intermediate container 895d13321da8
 Step 4/5 : RUN export http_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
  ---> Running in 19910745f212
  ---> 1de5b4fb2b2e
 Removing intermediate container 19910745f212
 Step 5/5 : RUN export
  ---> Running in e5d186b66385
 export HOME='/root'
 export HOSTNAME='26ba10d264c2'
 export NODE_VERSION='6.9.5'
 export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL='info'
 export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
 export PWD='/'
 export SHLVL='1'
  ---> 0aa0f97555bf
 Removing intermediate container e5d186b66385
 Successfully built 0aa0f97555bf
```

As you can see the export on the shell is not done!

When I open a shell in the newly build image and execute the commands manually it works.

```
> docker run myimage:latest sh
/ # export https_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
/ # export http_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
/ # export 
export HOME='/root'
export HOSTNAME='a759e3d30481'
export NODE_VERSION='6.9.5'
export NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL='info'
export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
export PWD='/'
export SHLVL='1'
export TERM='xterm'
export http_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
export https_proxy='http://myproxy:8080'
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to define ENV variable in a Dockerfile, better use `ENV` see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env

and by the way, group your RUN, see the doc explaining it

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/